# Publishing .NET web service to Jetty web server?

Tags: .net, web-services, jetty

I have created a very simple webservice using C# in VS2008.  I would like to publish this to a server using Jetty-6 as its web server.  Is this possible, or is IIS the only way I can go.

Answer (score 1):

IIS isn't the only way you can go.  Web Services using WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) can be published in the [following ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx):

- Self-hosting in any managed .NET application
- Hosting in a Windows service
- Hosting in different versions of IIS

This article breaks down pros and cons of the different options:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx

In any case, each one is pretty simple to do.  You should find templates for these options in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is a Java web server, so I doubt you'll be able to use C# code in Jetty itself... you can of course use something like HttpClient in Jetty to communicate with your C# service over HTTP.